# Modal not loading at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get a modal to open upon clicking a word in the footer, but absolutely nothing is happening. Here is the modal code:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 footerLeft"><a href="#aboutit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutit">about</a></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="aboutit">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Caesar's Cipher</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Explanation.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Learn More</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Close</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the modal to open when you click the word "about" on the bottom left. [Here is](http://codepen.io/l-emi/full/zBENra/) the codepen of the whole thing.

Thank you to all :)

EDIT. Here's the head section:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>

    <!-- bootstrap files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cipher.css">


    <title>CIPHER</title>
</head>
```

EDIT 2: jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fxrLymrq/

Comment: did you load to the page bootstrap model js file?

Comment: it works perfectly, [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3d1sunbt/) probably you missed a js or css file.

Comment: Strange, I can't figure out what. Thanks for the fiddle, at least I know I'm getting something right

Comment: @l-emi it think you miss located your script or something. if you can upload your head section maybe we can find your problem.

Comment: @ShlomiHaver edited to include head section

Answer (score 1):

You should load these js files in your header also:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

this should run your modal code.

I fixed your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxrLymrq/1/) you have to add the script files of the bootsrap.js and also you can get rid of this code:

```
$('#aboutit').ready(function() {
  $('#aboutit').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: @l-emi can you upload a fiddle with your entire code that relates to your problem? it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Sure, give me a sec

Answer (score 1):

**WORKING CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="col-lg-5 footerLeft"><a href="#aboutit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aboutit">about</a></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="aboutit">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Caesar's Cipher</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Explanation.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn" >Learn More</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other Change: data-dismiss="modal" applied to close button

Comment: Hey, it works! Thanks :) The only issue is that it busted my styling and layout :/

Comment: I figured out that when I remove my css sheet from the html the modal works, but it looks messed up (obviously if there's no styling). However if I add it back in, the modal doesn't work. Why could this be?

Comment: Fixed it, now modal pops up fine. However it isn't aligned well like before, I want the two links to be right at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116869/discussion-between-pranjal-and-l-emi).